# form in symfony does not exist

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm testing a simple page of contact with symfony but when i want to display the contact.html.twig it doesn't appear and i have the error that the form does not exist

there is my controller

```
 public function sendAction()
{
   $contact = new Contact();

   $form = $this->createForm(new ContactType(),$contact);

   $_REQUEST = $this->getRequest();

   if($_REQUEST->isMethod('Post')){
       $form->bind($_REQUEST);

       if($form->isValid()){

           $contact = $form->getData();

           $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
           $em->persist($contact);
           $em.flush();

           return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('front_office_send'));
       }
   }
    return $this->render('frontOfficeBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));

}
```

and my page contact.html.twig:

```
{% extends"frontOfficeBundle::layoutheader.html.twig" %}
{% block container %}
<form id="form" class="form-light mt-20" role="form" method="post" action="{{ path('front_office_send') }}">

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Nom</label>
                            {{form_widget(form.nom)}}

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Adresse électronique &nbsp;</label>
                                    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}

                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label>Téléphone</label>
                                    {{ form_widget(form.tel) }}

                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Sujet &nbsp;</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.sujet) }}

                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Message&nbsp;</label>
                            {{ form_widget(form.message) }}

                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-light">Annuler</button>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">

                                {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
                                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-base btn-icon btn-icon-right btn-fly pull-right">
                                    <span>Envoyer message</span>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
```

i have this routing:

```
front_office_send:
 path:     /Contact
 defaults: { _controller: frontOfficeBundle:Contact:send }
```

the error begin in the this line {{form_widget(form.nom)}} with the  variable form does not exist.

Comment: Please, paste a complete error output. We have no idea what "does not exist" means.

Comment: the error is this Variable "form" does not exist in frontOfficeBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig at line 48 and the line 48 is this : {{form_widget(form.nom) }}

Comment: in the stack trace i have if ($ignoreStrictCheck || !$this->env->isStrictVariables()) {
return;
}
throw new Twig_Error_Runtime(sprintf('Variable "%s" does not exist', $item), -1, $this->getTemplateName());
}
return $context[$item];
}

Comment: seems all correct, the only thing i see is a typo in the `$em.flush();` instead of `$em->flush();` try simply empty the cache and try again...

Comment: always the same error, i forgot the -> i have changed but the same error

Comment: try to dump something to check if it is going through your method sendAction

Comment: No when I write the URL of the contact page in the first time I got the error

Answer (score 1):

If you put

```
{{ form_widget(form) }}
```

it will show the whole form,

If you put

```
{{ form_widget(form.something) }}
```

You mean the field something, so you cannot do that, you have to do it on the first way.

If you want to show just one field (like I think you want...) you should do form_row

```
{{ form_row(form.nom) }}
```

Here you have the documentation

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template

Comment: i have tried the form_row and always the same error

Answer (score 0):

My guess is your form builder is incorrect.  I make this assumption based off the fact that you did not include your ContactType.php in the question.  Your form_widgets must coincide with the fields declared in the form builder.  Also, as stated in comments, there are multiple errors in your controller.

Here is a full list of a quick test page that I built using the pieces of information that you provided, it should get you started:

routing.yml:

```
front_office_send:
 path:     /test
 defaults: { _controller: SCWDesignsBundle:Test:test }
 requirements:
    _method:   GET|POST
```

Controller - Obviously change namespaces:

```
<?php
    namespace SCWDesignsBundle\Controller;

    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
    use SCWDesignsBundle\Entity\Test;
    use SCWDesignsBundle\Form\TestType;

    class TestController extends Controller {
        public function testAction(Request $request) {
           $contact = new Test();
           $form = $this->createForm(new TestType(), $contact);
           $form->handleRequest($request);

           if($form->isValid()) {
            $em->persist($contact);
            $em->flush();

            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('front_office_send'));
          }

          return $this->render('SCWDesignsBundle:Test:test.html.twig', array('form' => $form->createView()));
        }
    }
```

Entity:

```
<?php
    namespace SCWDesignsBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /**
     * @ORM\Entity
     * @ORM\Table(name="test")
     */
    class Test {
        /**
         * @ORM\ID
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        protected $id;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $nom;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL")
         */
        protected $email;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL")
         */
        protected $tel;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL")
         */
        protected $sujet;

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", columnDefinition="VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL")
         */
        protected $message;
}
```

FormType:

```
<?php
    namespace SCWDesignsBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

    class TestType extends AbstractType {
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
             $builder
                ->add('nom')
                ->add('email')
                ->add('tel')
                ->add('sujet')
                ->add('message');
        }

        public function getName() {
            return 'test_form';
        }
    }
```

View Page:

```
{% block container %}
<form id="form" class="form-light mt-20" role="form" method="post" action="{{ path('front_office_send') }}">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Nom</label>
            {{form_widget(form.nom)}}

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Adresse électronique &nbsp;</label>
                    {{ form_widget(form.email) }}

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Téléphone</label>
                    {{ form_widget(form.tel) }}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Sujet &nbsp;</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.sujet) }}

        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Message&nbsp;</label>
            {{ form_widget(form.message) }}

        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <button type="reset" class="btn btn-light">Annuler</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6">

                {{ form_widget(form._token) }}
                <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-base btn-icon btn-icon-right btn-fly pull-right">
                    <span>Envoyer message</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Results:

[image: Results of page]

Answer (score 0):

My form builder is like this :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('nom')
        ->add('email')
        ->add('tel')
        ->add('sujet')
        ->add('message')
    ;
}
```

i have added it the `requirements:
    _method:   GET|POST`
but always the form does not exist

Comment: and i my logs i have this : CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Twig_Error_Runtime: "Variable "form" does not exist in "frontOfficeBundle:Contact:contact.html.twig" at line 47" at C:\wamp\www\Symfony\app\cache\dev\classes.php line 4546